Vite Hot Reload Causes Child Component to Re-fetch and Duplicate Data in Vue 3 Composition API
I'm working on a Vue 3 project using the Composition API with TypeScript (), and I'm encountering an issue related to Vite's hot module replacement (HMR).
Problem Description:
Parent Component:
I have a ref variable called data in the parent component.
I'm passing this data to a child component using two-way binding via v-model:data="data".
In the parent component's template, I have a v-for loop that creates icons for each element in data.
ParentComponent.vue:

<template>
  <ChildComponent v-model:data="data" />
  <div v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">
    <!-- Display icon for each item -->
    <v-icon>mdi-blank-circle</icon>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';
import Icon from './Icon.vue';

const data = ref([]);
</script>

Child Component:
In the child component, I use defineModel to define the data model.
I have an asynchronous fetchData function that fetches data and assigns it to data.value.
I'm calling onMounted(fetchData()) to fetch data when the component mounts.
ChildComponent.vue:

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineModel, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { getMyData } from './api';

const data = defineModel('data');

const fetchData = async () => {
  data.value = await getMyData();
};

onMounted(fetchData());
</script>


Whenever Vite performs a hot reload in Child component code(e.g., adding some console.log in code), the child component re-fetches the data.
This re-fetching updates the parent's data, causing duplicate entries.
As a result, the icons in the parent component's v-for loop are duplicated.
The issue is that parent component is not rerendered, only child is rerenderd and that is causing next fetchData and double way binding is updating value in parent component with next fetch data.
For example:
1.first view loading :4 icons
2.some change in child component: 8 icons
And so on….
When I use reload button in browser, all works correctly and I have 4 icons displayed.

How can I prevent the child component from re-fetching data and causing duplicates in the parent component when Vite's hot reload occurs?

Is there a recommended pattern or best practice in Vue 3 with the Composition API and Vite to handle this situation?


Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

My understanding is that when a hot reload occurs, Vite cannot know exactly the impact of the reload. Therefore, it will remove the components that were touched by the hot reload from the dom, recreate them, and remount them.  Since they are remounted the mounted hook will fire again.
Now as for a fix...  There are many considerations but here are a couple of ideas.

Ensure that the data is top-down.  If you see the components as a tree, the leaves should rarely fetch data that is used higher.  This means that the parent components should manage the fetching.  If the child needs to add a filter and other consider emitting custom events.

Clear the list before setting some data into it. Always start with a clean state so if it mounts and unmounts for some reason at least it will restart fresh.

Using a store as pinia can help share data between components that are far aways in the components tree.

You Could always add a semaphore-like gate.  Add a const isLoaded = ref(false) and ounce initialized it prevents to load again.  Here again it is  in the parent or at least you can check that data.value is [] before fetching.


In short, in my small experience, usually, the page or a form will be responsible for the data flow.  Therefore I tend to keep them responsible for the fetchs and the children either emit or modify the query via v-model.  In the case where a components manage itself, I usually add a store to manage its state.  Finally, I avoid mostly mounted hooks because v-if will unmount and remount whereas v-show will not. This may be desirable in some cases but then why not just use create.
Last thing ensure that vite is at its latest version. ;)
